# Form Validation JavaScript - No Alert Appearing

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am having troubles with the form validation on my form. I have searched around and have tried a few things but have not found a solution. I am still learning JavaScript so I am sure it's something wrong with that. Below is my code.

HTML

```
<section>
<p>Please type in your information so I can send you the newsletter.<br>
Required values are marked by an asterisk (*)</p>     
<form id="newsletter" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method "post">
<fieldset id="personal">
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
<label for="name">Name: *</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40"> 
<br>
<label for="eMail">E-mail Address: *</label>
<input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail">
<br>
<label for="favBeer">Favorite Beer Style:</label>
<select name="favBeer" id="favBeer">
    <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
    <option value="Saison">Saison</option>
    <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
    <option value="Pilsner">Pilsner</option>
    <option value="Hefeweizen">Hefeweizen</option>
    <option value="Stout">Stout</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
<br>
<label for="comments"> Additional Information:<label>
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>  
</fieldset>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
function validateForm() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    if(nameValid(name)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function nameValid(name) {
    var name_length = name.length;
    if (name_length == "") {
        alert("Name is required");
        name.focus();
        return false;
    }
return ture;
}
```

Comment: First thing I notice is that you might be returning `ture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. `ture` should be `true`
2. You don't close your `form` tag
3. There's no `submit` button
4. You're comparing a string's length to `""`, instead of to a number.

But mainly, you're trying to take the length of an `input` (`name`), instead of the length of its `value`.

Instead:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  if (nameValid(name)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function nameValid(name) {
  var name_length = name.value.length;
  if (name_length == 0) {
    alert("Name is required");
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Please type in your information so I can send you the newsletter.
    <br>Required values are marked by an asterisk (*)</p>
  <form id="newsletter" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method "post">
    <fieldset id="personal">
      <legend>Personal Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="40">
      <br>
      <label for="eMail">E-mail Address: *</label>
      <input type="text" name="eMail" id="eMail">
      <br>
      <label for="favBeer">Favorite Beer Style:</label>
      <select name="favBeer" id="favBeer">
        <option value="IPA">IPA</option>
        <option value="Saison">Saison</option>
        <option value="Porter">Porter</option>
        <option value="Pilsner">Pilsner</option>
        <option value="Hefeweizen">Hefeweizen</option>
        <option value="Stout">Stout</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="comments">Additional Information:
        <label>
          <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="55" rows="5"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: That seemed to work. Thank you very much for your fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of the `name` element, not just the element itself.  I.e.:

```
document.getElementById("name").value
```

You also need to compare `length` properly as a numeric value, as in this updated function:

```
function nameValid(name) {
    var name_length = name.length;
    alert(name_length);
    if (name_length < 1) {
        alert("Name is required");
        //name.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Fiddle here include an extra alert: http://jsfiddle.net/799vymrz/

(although `console.log` is typically more helpful than `alert` for values you're debugging; you'll need to view your browser console to see the output of `console.log`)

Comment: When I try your ideas I don't get the alert. And when I when I try console.log I don't get anything either.